# How to parse a Json response and store some attributes

Tags: c#, json

I'm currently trying to parse the response from this link: https://api.ote-godaddy.com/v1/domains.

Now in my program I should get this type of response:

```
[
  {
    "createdAt": "2015-06-15T13:10:43.000Z",
    "domain": "000.biz",
    "domainId": 1002111,
    "expirationProtected": false,
    "expires": "2016-06-14T23:59:59.000Z",
    "exposeWhois": false,
    "holdRegistrar": false,
    "locked": true,
    "nameServers": null,
    "privacy": false,
    "renewAuto": true,
    "renewable": false,
    "status": "TRANSFERRED_OUT",
    "transferAwayEligibleAt": "2016-07-29T23:59:59.000Z",
    "transferProtected": false
  },
  {
    "createdAt": "2015-06-15T13:10:43.000Z",
    "domain": "000.biz",
    "domainId": 1002111,
    "expirationProtected": false,
    "expires": "2016-06-14T23:59:59.000Z",
    "exposeWhois": false,
    "holdRegistrar": false,
    "locked": true,
    "nameServers": null,
    "privacy": false,
    "renewAuto": true,
    "renewable": false,
    "status": "TRANSFERRED_OUT",
    "transferAwayEligibleAt": "2016-07-29T23:59:59.000Z",
    "transferProtected": false
  }
]
```

And I need to parse it to get **EVERY** `domain` attribute and write it. This is what I came up with:

```cs
const string WEBSERVICE_URL = "https://api.ote-godaddy.com/v1/domains?statuses=&includes=";
try
{
    var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(WEBSERVICE_URL);
    if (webRequest != null)
    {
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.Timeout = 12000;
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "sso-key " + api_key + ":" + api_secret);

        using (System.IO.Stream s = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s))
            {
                var jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
                if (jsonResponse == "[]")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No domains found");
                    bad = +1;
                }
                else
                {
                    JArray jo = JArray.Parse(jsonResponse);
                    hit = +1;
                    string hit_txt = "";
                    hit_txt = api_key + ":" + api_secret + "=" + jo[]["domain"];
                                        

                    Console.WriteLine(hit_txt);
                    using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter("hit.txt"))
                    {
                       writetext.WriteLine(hit_txt);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Don't worry about the other variables like `api_key`, everything is working fine)

Unfortunately I get this error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException:
> Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', >line 1, position 1.

Comment: As the error says, you are trying to parse an array as an object. Try something like `JArray.Parse()` instead of `JObject.Parse()`.

Comment: yes but it only write the first domain in the json response

Comment: Well, your JSON is invalid, since double double quotes is too many quotes.

Comment: I know, I just miss-tipped...

Comment: It sounds like my comment fixes the error you are asking about here. If you have another problem, please post a new question with the updated code.

Comment: I have actually still the same error, you comment was helpful but did not resolve my issue....

Comment: You should write the real **jsonResponse** here in your code block. `JArray jo = JArray.Parse(**jsonResponse**);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given scenario, specific value from Json can be selected by using `JArray` as:

```
JArray jo = JArray.Parse(jsonResponse);

//Get all "domain" elements from the Json
var domainNames = string.Join(", ", jo 
                     .Select(jt => jt["domain"])
                     .ToList());

//Then use this comma separated "domainNames" in the string
string hit_txt = "";
hit_txt = api_key + ":" + api_secret + "=" + domainNames;
```

If required to get collection of that elements, get without `string.Join` as:

```
var domainNames = jo 
                  .Select(jt => jt["domain"])
                  .ToList();
```

The collection can be used further anywhere.